# React-data-export multiple excel file download

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-hooks

I am using [react-data-export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-export) library for downloading my data into excel. It's working fine.
**but I having requirement to download multiple excel files in one click**. Checked official docs also, nothing mentioned regarding this. Below code working fine for single excel file download FYR. **Also having requirement to zip these excels**. If anyone experience this, please revert

```
import ReactExport from 'react-data-export';

const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;
const ExcelColumn = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelColumn;

const VesselReportExcelGenerator = (props) => {
    const [exportModalOpen, setExportModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [excelData, setExcelData] = useState([]);
    const vesselReportApi = new VesselReportApi();
    const loggedInVesselName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedVessel'))?.name;
    var generatedData = [
        {
            columns: columns,
            data: excelData
        }
    ];

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchVesselReportFormStructure();
    }, []);

    const fetchVesselReportFormStructure = async () => {
        try {
            const vesselReportFormStructure = await vesselReportApi.getVesselReportFormStructure();
            setExcelData(vesselReportFormStructure);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            props.setMessages([{type : "danger", message : 'Something went wrong. Please try again!'}]);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Container fluid className="VesselReportExcelBackground">
            <Col lg={7}>
                <Row style={{ justifyContent: 'center', height: '2rem',paddingTop: "40px",height: "10%" }}>
                    <div style={{fontSize: "2rem",color: config.KSTColors.MAIN,fontWeight: "900",}}>
                        OFFLINE VESSEL REPORT
                    </div>
                </Row>
                {/* Export Vessel report excel UI */}
                <Row xs={12} md={3} style={{backgroundColor: config.KSTColors.CARD_BG,height: "150px",borderRadius: "15px",marginTop: "40px"}}>
                    <Col xs={3} lg={3} style={{ padding: "0px" }}>
                        <Button className="VesselReportExcelEditButton" style={{ backgroundColor: config.KSTColors.MAIN,borderColor: config.KSTColors.MAIN,width: "100%"}} onClick={() => setExportModalOpen(true)}>
                            {/* <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFileExport} style={{color: config.KSTColors.ICON,fontSize: "60px"}} /> */}
                            <img src={VesselExportIMG} alt="Excel Export" style={{height: "120px"}}/>
                        </Button>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={6} lg={6}>
                        <div style={{display: "flex",width: "100%",height: "100%",flexDirection: "column",justifyContent: "center"}}>
                            <div style={{marginTop: "5px",width: "100%",height: "50%",color: config.KSTColors.MAIN,fontSize: "32px",
                                display: "flex",justifyContent: "center",alignItems: "center"}}>
                                Download Template
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Col>
            <Modal size="lg" show={exportModalOpen} onHide = {() => setExportModalOpen(false)} aria-labelledby="VRTemplateDownload" centered>
                <Modal.Header style={{ backgroundColor: '#e6e6e6' }}>
                    <Modal.Title id="VRTemplateDownload">Export Vessel Report Template</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <span style={{fontSize: "12px"}}>Are you sure to generate {loggedInVesselName} vessel report?</span>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer style={{ color: '#04588e' }}>
                    <Button onClick={() => setExportModalOpen(false)} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', color: '#04588e', paddingTop: '2px', paddingBottom: '2px', paddingLeft: '20px', paddingRight: '20px' }}>Cancel</Button>
                    <ExcelFile filename={`${loggedInVesselName}_DailyLogTemplate`} element={<Tooltip title="Export Daily Log Template" placement="bottom"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#04588e', color: 'white', paddingTop: '2px', paddingBottom: '2px', paddingLeft: '20px', paddingRight: '20px' }}>Daily Log</Button></Tooltip>}>
                        <ExcelSheet dataSet={generatedData} name="Daily Log" />
                    </ExcelFile>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default withMessageManager(VesselReportExcelGenerator);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have searched and there is no way to download multiple excel files using **react-data-export library**. So I have did some hack using **useRef** hook to implement this.

- I have make ExcelFile components hidden.
- Added a new button component and in onClick I have manually triggered
  excelFile onClick property.
- so can able to download multiple excel files.

Below code FYR. Cheers!!!

```
const dailyLogRef = useRef(null);
const morningShiftRef = useRef(null);

const formTemplateDownload = () => {
        dailyLogRef.current.click();
        morningShiftRef.current.click();
    }

<Tooltip title="Daily log,Morning shift & Evening shift templates download" placement="bottom"><Button onClick={() => formTemplateDownload()} style={{ backgroundColor: '#04588e', color: 'white', paddingTop: '2px', paddingBottom: '2px', paddingLeft: '20px', paddingRight: '20px' }}>Download Templates</Button></Tooltip>
<ExcelFile filename={`${loggedInVesselName}_DailyLogTemplate`} element={<Tooltip title="Export Daily Log Template" placement="bottom"><Button ref={dailyLogRef} style={{ backgroundColor: '#04588e', color: 'white', paddingTop: '2px', paddingBottom: '2px', paddingLeft: '20px', paddingRight: '20px',display: "none" }}>Daily Log</Button></Tooltip>}>
  <ExcelSheet dataSet={generatedData} name="Daily Log" />
</ExcelFile>
<ExcelFile filename={`${loggedInVesselName}_MorningShiftTemplate`} element={<Tooltip title="Export Morning Shift Template" placement="bottom"><Button ref={morningShiftRef} style={{ backgroundColor: '#04588e', color: 'white', paddingTop: '2px', paddingBottom: '2px', paddingLeft: '20px', paddingRight: '20px',display: "none" }}>Morning Shift</Button></Tooltip>}>
  <ExcelSheet dataSet={morningShiftLogGeneratedData} name="Morning Shift Log" />
</ExcelFile>
```